# Visual Studio 2013 can't create any project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

i have problems with visual studio 2013:
when i try to create any project (f.e: c# console app), then i see always this window:

[image]

and when i try to click anywhere, then i see the cloud:
"microsoft visual studio is busy waiting for an internal operation to complete"

but when i'm open visual studio 2013 by developer command prompt for vs2013 → devenv/safemode

then i can everything, but i can't open team explorer (for git).

how can i resolve this problem?

Edit:
I try do it for 10 minutes. after ~8 minutes i see my project solution...but it's to sloow :/

Edit2:
it's my extensions:
[image]

Comment: Is this in a virtual machine or on native hardware?

Comment: not virtual, normal :-)

Comment: Are you meeting the minimum system requirements for Visual Studio 2013, including processor speed and cores, RAM and available disk space?

Comment: What else is running, and have you rebooted recently?

Comment: yes, i didn't see any warnings before instalation.

Comment: not before intallation, available disk space and ram at the moment you try to create project.

Comment: i have open other apps, but in my windows manager i see that CPU use 50-60% and 2/3.15(?)GB

Comment: 2/3.15(?)GB you mean between 2 and 3.15 gb harddisk space?

Comment: is used 2GB RAM, full size: 3.15 GB

Comment: check your disk space...if bellow 10 probably the answer....

Comment: i have a lot space on disk...below 10? unity?

Comment: Did you install any plugin? I guess they are not being loaded in safe mode. It seems, although awkward, that something is waiting for a timeout

Comment: yes, i have plugins, wait for edit (2 sec)

Comment: I read you have git; maybe git extension is trying to reach an unreachable endpoint and hence the timeout

Comment: Do the usual troubleshooting... Check for viruses, run Task Manager and check the CPU utilization, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A few things that come to mind, which you may want to verify:

1. Do you have a virus, malware or hung CPU hogging process or memory leaking process?  Check how much system resources are free in Task Manager.  Install and update anti-virus software such as Microsoft Security Essentials (free), if you don't have any.
2. Is Visual Studio up to date with the latest updates and software patches?
3. Do you have any Visual Studio extensions or addons installed which may be causing the lag?  Try disabling them all to see if the problem still occurs.
4. Are your projects being created and saved to a network drive which is extremely slow to access, or is your hard disk unresponsive due to other I/O happening in the background?

Comment: 1 - ok
2 - i have update 1
3 - yes, look in newest vesion my question
4 - not, only local PC